# Conditional SQL Query Which Sums ALL TimeEntires of Related Task if any TimeEntries Updated in Last 10 Days

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, having-clause

I have a database with columns

```
timeEntryIDs (Primary KEY), 
taskAssignmentIDs, 
Spent(Sum of two columns product), and 
updatedAT.
```

It has multiple timeEntries for every taskAssignmentID all added/updated at different dates.

I am trying to build an SQL query that I can run on a weekly basis to give me the TOTAL spent on every taskAssignmentID where updatedAT is greater than today's date minus 10 days.

So basically if a timeEntry has been made or updated in the last 10 days, provide the new total Spent on that taskAssignmentID.

I have tried and failed to come up with this, any help would be appreciated. Here is the best I could do:

```
SELECT projectName
     , projectID
     , clientName
     , clientID
     , taskName
     , taskAssignmentID
     , SUM(userAssignment_hourlyRate * roundedHours) AS 'Spent'
     , updatedAt 
  FROM DB
 WHERE updatedAt > ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), -10) 
 GROUP 
    BY taskAssignmentID
```

The problem with this is it only SUMS time entries updated in the last 10 days. I want ALL time entries for a given taskAssignmentID IF any timeEntry pointing to that taskAssignmentID has been updated in the last 10 days.

Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
select taskassignmentid, sum(userassignment_hourlyrate * roundedhours) as spent
from mytable
group by taskassignmentid
having max(updatedat) >= current_date - interval 10 day
```

This computes the overal spent for each `taskassignmentid` whose latest `updatedat` is less than 10 days old.

Notes:

- I fixed the original code to make it a valid aggregation query; the columns in the `select` and `group by` clause must be *consistent*: every non-aggregated column in the `select` clause must be repeated in the `group by` clause (left alone functionaly-dependent columns - but your question does not mention that)
- don't use single quotes for identifiers (such as column aliases)! They should be used for literal strings only; use backticks for identifiers, or better yet, use identifiers that don't need to be quoted

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Also, thanks for the tips : )